# How to install APCu with PHP 7.4

Tags: php, macos

I installed php 7.4 onto OSX 12.1 onto a MacBook with Apple M1 Max Chip.

I followed this instruction:
https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-monterey-apache-mysql-vhost-apc

Now I try to install APCu. But I get this error message:

In file included from /private/tmp/pear/temp/apcu/php_apc.c:34:
In file included from /private/tmp/pear/temp/apcu/apc_iterator.h:26:
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.27/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:25:10: fatal error: 'pcre2.h' file not found
#include "pcre2.h"
^~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [php_apc.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed

How can I fix that problem?

Thanks for help.

Comment: "pcre" is the Perl regex library, you probably should install the pcre lib-dev (for development), library or PHP pcre module source,

Comment: It is installed.
pcre 8.45 is already installed and up-to-date

Comment: So possible reasons are - was the "dev" version installed? - can the path to the includes / libs fbe found? (compiler options...)

Comment: cd /opt/homebrew/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.27/include/php/ext/pcre is available, but there is only the file php_pcre.h saved

Comment: There shouldn't be so many files. You can access the file, but does the compiler know how to reach it?

Comment: I checked php_pcre.h into line 25
#include "pcre2.h"
But with # it should not be loaded, right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I find the problem.
Brew installed pcre2 to another directory.
I copied the file with this command, and then it worked:

cp /opt/homebrew/Cellar/pcre2/10.39/include/pcre2.h /opt/homebrew/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.27/include/php/ext/pcre/

Comment: indeed, `cp /usr/local/homebrew/Cellar/pcre2/10.40/include/pcre2.h /usr/local/homebrew/Cellar/php@8.0/8.0.15/include/php/ext/pcre` worked for me :)
Thank you very much

Comment: For me worked too, thanks
I just needed update 39 to 42